# How do I reference controls on different subforms in a tab control?

Tags: ms-access, tabcontrol, subform

So I have a tab control with a subform on each page. I'm trying to add values from several different textboxes on each subform. I have no problem referencing the textboxes and getting a total on the same subforme, example (= txtOne + txtTwo). However, I'm having problems trying to reference the textboxes on the other subforms in the tab control. I'm sure it's just a syntax issue. Keep getting a Name? error.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: http://allenbrowne.com/casu-04.html

Comment: http://access.mvps.org/access/forms/frm0031.htm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From one subform to reference an object on a sister subform, visit the *parent* object (the main form):

```
OtherValue = Me.Parent!NameOfSisterSubformControl.Form!OtherControl.Value
```

Edit - as expression:

```
=[txtOne]+[txtTwo]+[txtThree]+[Parent]![subFormControlName].[Form]![txtFour]
```

Comment: Still getting the same error. Page 3 on tab control has subform3.txtTotal. I'm adding =txtOne + txtTwo on subform3 and the total is coming out fine. When I add in another control (txtThree) from subform1 on page1 in the tab control using your suggestion, still getting a name? error.

Comment: =[txtOne]+[txtTwo]+[txtThree]+[Forms]![MainForm]![subForm].[Form]![txtFour]

Comment: I'm putting the above code in the control source of txtTotal

Comment: That was not what I wrote. I've edited the answer to include the style for an expression. Do note, that `[Form]` must be entered with your localised name for a Form object - could be `Formular`, and the it is name of the _subform control_ to use, not the name of the subform object.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. I'm not thinking of the subform as an actual control, only as a form.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. The controls are bound to a table and I just referenced that instead of the actual name of the control.